# PCB surface mount alternative for JST-XH connector

Tags: pcb, connector, soldering

I am having a very hard time finding an answer to this, most likely because it is rather difficult to search for items without knowing the acronyms or names for the connector types.

I have a PCB that contains what I believe to be a JST-XH connector with an accompanying female cable:

[image]

What I would like to do is make a new PCB that would contain the female connector so the boards would essentially plug into each other - stacking the boards. My problem is that I am having a very difficult time finding a female PCB surface mount JST (or whatever it is) connector.

Does anyone know if such a thing exists? If not, I see a few alternative options:

> 1. Remove the connector on the board and replace it with something like this [image]
>
> however removing existing components is typically a tricky business so
>   this is not ideal..
>
> 2. Connect the two PCBs with standoffs and use ribbon cables between the connectors; or
> 3. Strip away the wire housing and treat the wire like a pin to solder to the second board, which is less than ideal and will most likely be unreasonably messy.

Does anyone have any ideas for a scenario like this?

Comment: It's not SMD, but [this connector](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/08JQ-BT/455-2970-ND/4918702) will mate with the one on your board - allowing a 2-stack.

Comment: @ brhans This looks perfect!! Exactly what I was thinking of. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu are not likely to find JST makes a female mezzanine connector in either SMT or THT that matches this Board-to-Wire male Jack with offset shroud and interlocks designed for cable for plugs.

just use a THT header socket that fits.
[image]
https://www.digikey.com/products/en?mpart=929974-01-08-RK&v=19

Comment: Exactly.. I would also suggest using some other means of mechanically securing the boards together (e.g. standoff posts) so that you're not relying on the connector to locate or secure them.

Comment: I preferred flex or ribbon cable inter-board connections with hinged standoffs.

Comment: Standoffs shouldn't be an issue to secure the boards, but using a different connector requires removing the existing 8 pin connector. Is this easily accomplished without damaging other components or the traces?

Comment: You might be able to mate the existing Pins with the header I showed , otherwise a good vacuum solder sucker is needed to replace without damage.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in comments on another solution, use an alternative connector that can still fit within the JST header but that matches the pitch/spacing of the pins.  The other comments are implying this without explicitly pointing out that the key is the pitch of the pins, and I don't think the OP got that.

Also, that does not look like JST-XH to me but I'm not an expert.  For XH, the alignment/catch nubs are on one of the long sides, not on the ends.

But if it were an XH, for example, it is possible to plug a standard Dupont 2.54 pitch connector into the board side.  Then you could add a dab of hot glue to keep it there.